# Is it easier to make 1 file with lots of data or 4 files, each with 1 set of data?

Tags: file, file-io, python-2.5

I am making a program that will, among other things, create new objects with an instance variable called 'name'.  If  'name' is not passed into the method, then my code reads from a file that contains a set of male and female names and chooses one.  My file is called names.txt and is set up like so:

```
1. John, Alex, Adam, Matt, Sean, Max, . . .
2. John, Adam, Matt, Sean
3. Sarah, Mary, Alexa, Amy, Katie, . . .
4. Mary, Amy, Katie
```

The file is organized so that lines 1 and 3 are the list of all possible names for a person of that sex while lines 2 and 4 list the names for that sex that are not already used.  As can be seen, lines 1-2 are names for guys while lines 3-4 are for girls. The way I plan to use this file is to choose from lines 2 or 4 an available name (a 'read' operation) and then rewrite the line without that name (a 'write' operation)

Now that I have explained this, here is my question: with the way that python is able to perform operations to files, am I better off having multiple files, each with either 2 of the above lines or just 1, or is it better to have 1 big file? 
  Research that I did indicates that to remove/rewrite even a single name, I would have to read every line on file, make a copy of it in memory, and then completely re-enter all the data after taking out the one name.  Although I don't plan on having many lines of text, I do see myself possibly having hundreds of names on each of those 4 lines.  Having to create space for all of that data in memory just so I can remove one name from the file seems highly inefficient.
  The other thing I thought to do was to seperate the data into either 2 or 4 files. In the case of 2 files, I would have lines 1-2 on file 1 and lines 3-4 on file 2, and have to deal with the same problem that I mentioned in the paragraph above, except on a smaller scale (I'd have less data to worry about storing to memory).  In the case of 4 files, there would be almost no problem with storing the data, but now I'd have to worry about maintaining and keeping track of 4 files.  In doing this, I feel like I would be managing my resources better but that I would lose some degree of organization that I felt having all 4 lines in 1 file created.

So again I ask: is it better to have 1 big file to perform read/write operations on, or is it better to have multiple files, each containing one or two segments of the total data, to perform operations on?

Thanks for a reply!

-Max, an aspiring python programmer

ps.  This is my first post, and I am not sure if I provided too much info or not enough, please provide feedback on this if you can!

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry too much about inefficiency on one big file.

Generously assuming an average name length of 10 characters and 10.000 names you are still at 100Kb well below the current level of memory in a computer.

Actually you do not have to write out the file completely, for one thing you can write to a new file while reading a name at a time then after you are finished, remove the original and rename the new file to the original. That is essentially how the old computers did this with small memory and tape operations (writing to a new tape while sorting etc).

If you just want more efficiency, without the overhead of using a database, you can consider the following:

- Don't use text files, but save the names as a dictionary of as python list in pickled form. This should spead up reading and dumping the data. But it is not so easy to check the resulting file.
- If you want to stick with readable text, consider not having `,` between names, but either `,` (comma + space) after each name, or `.` (dot + space) after each name depending on the name having been used or not. If you open the file with `"w+"` and just rewrite the comma after a name to period when you use a name. This is much more efficient than rewriting the files, and your file would be more efficient because you are not doubling unused names.